# Script to automate enabling TDE on any unencypted user databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, transparent-data-encryption

I'm looking for a way to automate the encryption of user databases.  Ideally this would be a job that can be scheduled to run every night.  The job would: find any user database that is not encrypted, create the DEK (if it doesn't exist), and enable TDE.  We use the same Certificate/PK for each database on every server (for better or worse).  This certificate has been backed up.

I attempted this by creating the following stored procedure.  However, it occasionally fails with the following error:

> Executed as user: TAC_NT********. Msg 33107, Level 16, State 1, Server *******, Line 2
>   Cannot enable database encryption because it is already enabled.  Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Server *********, Line 2
>   ALTER DATABASE statement failed.  Encypting Database: *********  Warning: The certificate used for encrypting the database encryption key has not been backed up. 
>   You should immediately back up the certificate and the private key associated with the certificate. 
>   If the certificate ever becomes unavailable or if you must restore or attach the database on another server, 
>   you must have backups of both the certificate and the private key or you will not be able to open the database.
>   Encypting Database: *********.  Process Exit Code 1.  The step failed

The databases do get encrypted, but the job reports failure.

Here's the SP:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[sp_EncryptDBs] AS
BEGIN
    SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;
    SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;
/*  Get Databases that are online and have no DEK   */
    SELECT
        db_name(D.database_id) [Database]
    INTO #Databases
    FROM
        sys.databases D
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS
            (
                SELECT *
                FROM 
                    sys.dm_database_encryption_keys DEK
                WHERE
                    DEK.database_id = D.database_id
            )
        AND db_name(D.database_id) NOT IN
            (
                'Master',
                'model',
                'msdb'
            )
        AND D.state_desc = 'Online'
    WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Databases) > 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Database NVARCHAR(50) = (SELECT TOP 1 [Database] FROM #Databases)
        DECLARE @Command1 NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
            USE [' + @Database + ']
            CREATE DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256
            ENCRYPTION BY SERVER CERTIFICATE ********
            '
        DECLARE @Command2 NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
            ALTER DATABASE [' + @Database + ']
            SET ENCRYPTION ON
        '       
        PRINT 'Encypting Database: ' + @Database;
        EXEC sp_executesql @Command1 ;
        EXEC sp_executesql @Command2 ;
        --PRINT @Command1
        --PRINT @Command2
        DELETE FROM #Databases WHERE [Database] = @Database;
    END
    DROP TABLE #Databases;

/*  Databases that have a DEK but are in an unencypted state    */
    SELECT db_name(database_id) [Database]
    INTO #Databases2
    FROM 
        sys.dm_database_encryption_keys K
    WHERE
        K.encryption_state <> 3
    WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Databases2) > 0
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @Database2 NVARCHAR(50) = (SELECT TOP 1 [Database] FROM #Databases2)
            DECLARE @Command3 NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
                ALTER DATABASE [' + @Database2 + ']
                SET ENCRYPTION ON
            '   
            PRINT 'Encypting Database: ' + @Database2;
            --PRINT @Command3
            EXEC sp_executesql @Command3;
            DELETE FROM #Databases2 WHERE [Database] = @Database2
        END
        DROP TABLE #Databases2
END
GO
```

Comment: @ScottHodgin I think you're correct.  I updated the script to `K.encryption_state < 2' and then created a new database and executed the script without error.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was checking `K.encryption_state <> 3` (encrypted) to test whether I should enable encryption.

i should have also checked for encrypted (`K.encryption_state <> 2`) when testing the status.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated script with parameters:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'sp_EncryptDBs')
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.sp_EncryptDBs
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_EncryptDBs]
    @CertName NVARCHAR(128) = NULL,
    @BackupLocation NVARCHAR(256) = NULL,
    @Password NVARCHAR(128) = NULL,
    @ExpirationDate DATE = NULL,
    @MasterKeyPassword NVARCHAR(128) = NULL,
    @ExcludedDatabases NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @DropMasterKey NVARCHAR(3) = 'NO'
AS
BEGIN
    SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;
    SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Check if the backup location is valid and accessible
    DECLARE @BackupLocationExists INT = 1
    IF @BackupLocation IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            EXEC master.dbo.xp_create_subdir @BackupLocation
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            SET @BackupLocationExists = 0
        END CATCH

        PRINT 'Checking backup location: ' + @BackupLocation;
        PRINT 'Backup location exists: ' + CASE WHEN @BackupLocationExists = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END;

        IF @BackupLocationExists = 0
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Backup location is not valid or accessible. Cannot proceed with the operation.';
            RETURN;
        END
    END

    -- Create a new certificate if parameters are specified
    IF @CertName IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        -- If @MasterKeyPassword is not provided, cannot proceed with creating a new certificate
        IF @MasterKeyPassword IS NULL
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Cannot create a new certificate because the master key password is not provided.';
            RETURN;
        END

        -- Try to open the master key
        BEGIN TRY
            DECLARE @OpenMasterKeyCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
                OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = ''' + @MasterKeyPassword + '''';
            EXEC sp_executesql @OpenMasterKeyCommand;
            PRINT 'Opened master key';
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            PRINT 'Cannot open master key with the provided password.';
            RETURN;
        END CATCH

        -- If @DropMasterKey is 'YES', drop the encryption keys, certificate, and master key
        IF @DropMasterKey = 'YES'
        BEGIN
            -- Find databases with an encryption key and drop it
            DECLARE @DatabaseWithKey NVARCHAR(128)
            DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
            SELECT db_name(database_id) FROM sys.dm_database_encryption_keys
            OPEN cur
            FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @DatabaseWithKey
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @DropKeyCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
                    USE [' + @DatabaseWithKey + ']
                    DROP DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY';
                EXEC sp_executesql @DropKeyCommand;
                PRINT 'Dropped encryption key for database: ' + @DatabaseWithKey;
                FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @DatabaseWithKey
            END
            CLOSE cur
            DEALLOCATE cur

            -- Find the certificate used for TDE and drop it
            DECLARE @CertNameToDrop NVARCHAR(128) =
                (SELECT TOP 1 c.name FROM sys.certificates c WHERE c.pvt_key_encryption_type_desc = 'DATABASE')
            IF @CertNameToDrop IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @DropCertCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
                    USE master
                    DROP CERTIFICATE [' + @CertNameToDrop + ']';
                EXEC sp_executesql @DropCertCommand;
                PRINT 'Dropped certificate: ' + @CertNameToDrop;
            END

            -- Drop the master key
            EXEC sp_executesql N'DROP MASTER KEY';
            PRINT 'Dropped master key';
        END

        -- Switch to master database
        EXEC sp_executesql N'USE master';

        -- Create a new certificate
        DECLARE @CreateCertCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
            CREATE CERTIFICATE [' + @CertName + ']
            WITH SUBJECT = ''Database Encryption'',
            EXPIRY_DATE = ''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @ExpirationDate, 120) + '''';
        EXEC sp_executesql @CreateCertCommand;

        -- Backup the certificate
        IF @BackupLocation IS NOT NULL AND @Password IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @BackupCertCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
                BACKUP CERTIFICATE [' + @CertName + ']
                TO FILE = ''' + @BackupLocation + '\' + @CertName + '.cer''
                WITH PRIVATE KEY (FILE = ''' + @BackupLocation + '\' + @CertName + '.pvk'',
                ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = ''' + @Password + ''')';
            EXEC sp_executesql @BackupCertCommand;

            PRINT 'Created and backed up new certificate: ' + @CertName;
        END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- Check if there is an existing, non-expired certificate that is used for encryption in a user database
        SET @CertName = (
            SELECT TOP 1 c.name
            FROM sys.certificates c
            INNER JOIN sys.dm_database_encryption_keys dek ON dek.encryptor_thumbprint = c.thumbprint
            WHERE c.expiry_date > GETDATE()
        )

        IF @CertName IS NULL
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Cannot find an existing, non-expired certificate. Please provide a certificate name.';
            RETURN;
        END

        PRINT 'Using existing certificate: ' + @CertName;
    END

    -- Split the excluded databases into a table
    DECLARE @ExcludedDatabasesTable TABLE (DatabaseName NVARCHAR(128))
    DECLARE @DatabaseName NVARCHAR(128)
    WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @ExcludedDatabases) > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @DatabaseName = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@ExcludedDatabases, 1, CHARINDEX(',', @ExcludedDatabases) - 1))),
            @ExcludedDatabases = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@ExcludedDatabases, CHARINDEX(',', @ExcludedDatabases) + 1, LEN(@ExcludedDatabases))))
        INSERT INTO @ExcludedDatabasesTable (DatabaseName) VALUES (@DatabaseName)
    END
    INSERT INTO @ExcludedDatabasesTable (DatabaseName) VALUES (@ExcludedDatabases)

    -- Encrypt databases that are not yet encrypted and not in the excluded list
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Databases') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #Databases

    SELECT
        db_name(D.database_id) [Database]
    INTO #Databases
    FROM
        sys.databases D
    WHERE
        D.is_encrypted = 0
        AND db_name(D.database_id) NOT IN
            (
                'Master',
                'model',
                'msdb'
            )
        AND db_name(D.database_id) NOT IN
            (
                SELECT DatabaseName FROM @ExcludedDatabasesTable
            )
        AND D.state_desc = 'Online'

    DECLARE @Count INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Databases);
    PRINT 'Number of databases to encrypt: ' + CAST(@Count AS NVARCHAR(10));

    DECLARE @Database NVARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT [Database] FROM #Databases;

    OPEN db_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Database

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Current Database: ' + @Database;
        DECLARE @Command1 NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
            USE [' + @Database + ']
            CREATE DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256
            ENCRYPTION BY SERVER CERTIFICATE [' + @CertName + ']'
        DECLARE @Command2 NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
            ALTER DATABASE [' + @Database + ']
            SET ENCRYPTION ON
        '
        PRINT 'Encrypting Database: ' + @Database;
        PRINT 'Executing command: ' + @Command1;
        BEGIN TRY
            EXEC sp_executesql @Command1;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            PRINT 'Error executing command: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE();
        END CATCH
        PRINT 'Executing command: ' + @Command2;
        BEGIN TRY
            EXEC sp_executesql @Command2;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            PRINT 'Error executing command: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE();
        END CATCH

        FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Database
    END

    CLOSE db_cursor
    DEALLOCATE db_cursor

    SET @Count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Databases);
    PRINT 'Number of databases after loop: ' + CAST(@Count AS NVARCHAR(10));

    DROP TABLE #Databases;

    -- Switch encryption to the new or existing certificate for databases that have an expired certificate
    SELECT db_name(database_id) [Database]
    INTO #Databases2
    FROM
        sys.dm_database_encryption_keys K
        INNER JOIN sys.certificates C ON K.encryptor_thumbprint = C.thumbprint
    WHERE
        C.expiry_date < GETDATE()

    WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Databases2) > 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Database2 NVARCHAR(50) = (SELECT TOP 1 [Database] FROM #Databases2)
        DECLARE @Command3 NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
            USE [' + @Database2 + ']
            ALTER DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY
            ENCRYPTION BY SERVER CERTIFICATE [' + @CertName + ']'
        PRINT 'Switching encryption to certificate ' + @CertName + ' for Database: ' + @Database2;
        EXEC sp_executesql @Command3;
        DELETE FROM #Databases2 WHERE [Database] = @Database2
    END

    DROP TABLE #Databases2

    -- Close the master key, if it was opened
    IF @CertName IS NOT NULL AND @CertName = @CertName
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_executesql N'CLOSE MASTER KEY';
        PRINT 'Closed master key';
    END

    PRINT 'Database encryption completed successfully.';
END
GO
```